# Switch Catch all for 404 page stops render fn from sending props to component. (React-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Reacter Router Dom
Version
4.2.2

Steps to reproduce
I created a router and needed a catch all for my 404 error page so following the doumentation I added the

```
<React.Fragment>
<Switch>
<PublicRoute
  exact
  path={ROUTE.SIGN_IN}
  render={() => (
    <Authentication isSignUp={false} isLocalMode={isLocalMode} />
  )}
/>

<PublicRoute
  exact
  path={ROUTE.SIGN_UP}
  render={() => <Authentication isSignUp isLocalMode={isLocalMode} />}
/>

 <Route
  component={Error404}
/>
</Switch></ReactFragment>
```

## Expected Behavior

That the render function sends the props over to the Authentication component and can be used.

## Actual Behavior

The props isSignUp and isLocalMode keep coming back undefined and break the view.

How can I allow both the catch all and sending of the props work together? Is there another way because I was following the documentation as I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue...if anyone happens to have a problem with it you need to change render to component. 
In the documentation, it does not let you know that a function can be passed to the component, which is what stumped me.

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Switch>
     <PublicRoute
      exact
      path={ROUTE.SIGN_IN}
      component={() => 
       (<Authentication isSignUp={false} isLocalMode={isLocalMode} />)}
     />

     <PublicRoute
      exact
      path={ROUTE.SIGN_UP}
      component={() => <Authentication isSignUp isLocalMode={isLocalMode} />}
     />

    <Route
     component={Error404}
    />
  </Switch>
</ReactFragment>
```